# LibGDX - Unable to apply blur shader to actor

Tags: java, libgdx, shader

I extended the class **Image** to add the blur shader to this actor. It works fine for a full screen background image but it doesn't for small actors.

[image: screen with shader]

My icons are extracted from a TextureAtlas.

```
private ShaderProgram shader;
private float radius = 2f;

public BlurActor(Texture tex){
    super(tex);
    initShader();
}

public BlurActor(Sprite sprite){
    super(sprite);
    initShader();

}

private void initShader(){
    shader = new ShaderProgram(Gdx.files.internal("shaders/blur.vert"), Gdx.files.internal("shaders/blur.frag"));

    shader.begin();
    shader.setUniformf("dir", 0.0f, 0.0f); 
    shader.setUniformf("resolution", getHeight()); 
    shader.setUniformf("radius", radius); 
    shader.end();
}

@Override
public void draw(Batch batch, float alpha){

    batch.setShader(shader);

    shader.setUniformf("dir", 1.0f, 1.0f);
    shader.setUniformf("radius", radius);
    getDrawable().draw(batch, getX(), getY(), getWidth() * getScaleX(), getHeight() * getScaleY());

    batch.setShader(null);

}
```

Comment: Need to see your actual shader to know how it works to help you.

Answer (score 0):

As per Tenfour04 request here is are the shader files:

vert:

```
uniform mat4 u_projTrans;

attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord0;
attribute vec4 a_color;

varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;

void main() {
    gl_Position = u_projTrans * a_position;
    v_texCoord = a_texCoord0;
    v_color = a_color;
}
```

frag:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
precision mediump int;
#else
#define highp;
#endif


varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;

uniform sampler2D u_texture;
uniform float resolution;
uniform float radius;
uniform vec2 dir;

void main() {
    vec4 sum = vec4(0.0);
    vec2 tc = v_texCoord;

    // Number of pixels off the central pixel to sample from
    float blur = radius/resolution; 

    // Blur direction
    float hstep = dir.x;
    float vstep = dir.y;

    // Apply blur using 9 samples and predefined gaussian weights
    sum += texture2D(u_texture, vec2(tc.x - 4.0*blur*hstep, tc.y - 4.0*blur*vstep)) * 0.006;
    sum += texture2D(u_texture, vec2(tc.x - 3.0*blur*hstep, tc.y - 3.0*blur*vstep)) * 0.044;
    sum += texture2D(u_texture, vec2(tc.x - 2.0*blur*hstep, tc.y - 2.0*blur*vstep)) * 0.121;
    sum += texture2D(u_texture, vec2(tc.x - 1.0*blur*hstep, tc.y - 1.0*blur*vstep)) * 0.194;

    sum += texture2D(u_texture, vec2(tc.x, tc.y)) * 0.27;

    sum += texture2D(u_texture, vec2(tc.x + 1.0*blur*hstep, tc.y + 1.0*blur*vstep)) * 0.194;
    sum += texture2D(u_texture, vec2(tc.x + 2.0*blur*hstep, tc.y + 2.0*blur*vstep)) * 0.121;
    sum += texture2D(u_texture, vec2(tc.x + 3.0*blur*hstep, tc.y + 3.0*blur*vstep)) * 0.044;
    sum += texture2D(u_texture, vec2(tc.x + 4.0*blur*hstep, tc.y + 4.0*blur*vstep)) * 0.006;

    gl_FragColor = sum;
}
```